# Write square of vector elements as diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $x = (x_1,...,x_n)^T$ is some vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to write the square diagonal matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & x_2^2 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & x_n^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

in terms of some matrix/vector operations on $x$. I'm not even sure this is possible but my first though is use somehow use the matrix $xx^T$ because it has the correct diagonal, but then I'm not really sure what to subtract to get rid of the non-diagonal entries. Thanks for the help.

Comment: so we can only use $x$ and $x^T$? or what other things can we use?

Comment: Ideally yes only those two. But I'm open to any suggesting you have I just don't want something like $diag(x_1^2,...,x_n^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possibility for the $2\times2$ case - I think the extension to the $n\times n$ case is fairly obvious:
$$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}\pmatrix{x&y\cr}\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}=\pmatrix{x^2&0\cr0&0\cr}$$
and
$$\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1\cr}\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}\pmatrix{x&y\cr}\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1\cr}=\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&y^2\cr}$$
and adding these gives the matrix you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the desired matrix with
$$\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{x} \odot \mathbf{x}),$$
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product (element by element product).

If you don't want to use the $\mathrm{diag}$ operator, following your idea you can obtain the desired matrix with
$$(\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}) \odot \mathrm{I} = \mathrm{I} \odot (\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}),$$
where $\mathrm{I}$ is the identity matrix.

If you don't want to use the Hadamard product, then you need to sum different results as shown in @David's answer or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2346213/856328).