# Write this sum in matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

## Problem

Let $B$ be a $k\times t$ matrix and for each $i=1, \ldots n$ let $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $z_i\in\mathbb{R}^t$ be vectors. Let $y_i\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real number for ever $i$. I have the following expression and I would like to summarize it using matrix notation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left[y_i - x_i^\top B z_i\right]^2.
$$

## Solution Attempt

Set $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)^\top$. Construct the matrix
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1^\top \\
\vdots \\
    x_n^\top
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}
$$
Then $XB$ would take care of the $n$ terms $x_i^\top B$. However I am not sure about how to put the $z_i$ together. Ideally I would like to write something like this
$$
\|y - XB ? Z\|_2^2
$$
where $?$ is some mysterious operation and $Z$ a matrix constructed from the $z_i$ somehow.

Comment: If you construct $Z$ as a $t \times n$ matrix using the vectors $z_i$ as columns, then inside the norm you want $y-\operatorname{diag}(XBZ)$, where $\operatorname{diag}$ returns a vector that has the same entries as the diagonal of the matrix. I'm not sure if there's some other way write that.

Comment: That looks good! I guess then the question is how to write $\text{diag}(XBZ)$ as matrix-vector operations. Although according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346143/mathematical-operator-to-extract-diagonal-elements-of-a-square-matrix) one can write $\text{diag}(XBZ)=\sum_{i=1}^n (e_i^\top XBZ e_i)e_i$

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to use summation notation, then isn't your original equation better? Is there something specific you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Since the expression is three dimensional, I don't think you're going to get anything better than the original notation if you use matrix notation. Maybe you should use tensor notation instead?